# Table valued functions in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I recently learned that table valued functions are not allowed with Entity Framework 4.1.
Having read the comment to this correct answer [Table-Valued Functions in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294667/table-valued-functions-in-entity-framework) - I figured that I needed to download the June 2011 CTP to use TVFs in my project.

I downloaded and installed the CTP. A lot of the new functions are now available to choose from but I still can't import TVFs. I go to my EDMX file, right-click and go to 'Update Model from Database' but everything in the *DATABASENAME/Programability/Functions/Table-valued Functions/* cannot be imported even though that blog specified otherwise.

I then decided to go to the latest version of EF - I downloaded EF v4.3.1 using the NuGet package manager and it is still no use.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TVF with EF 4.0. Take a look here

[Table Valued Functions in EF](http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Using-table-valued-database-functions-with-Entity-Framework-40.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tabish, that worked a treat! However, it seems a bit tedious to have to modify the SSDL itself. Anyone know when/if we can import them just like Stored Procs?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-table-valued-functions-june-ctp.aspx